# Measuring performance of web service

Tags: java, performance, web-services, rest

I have a REST based Java web service written using Spring. It has three components
1)Query Redis cache.
2)Query Mongo db.
3)Write into mysql db.
I want to measure component wise response times of web service.
Are there any tools available which I can use to profile web service so that I can find out which component is bottleneck in the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can try jMeter for load test - http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use JETM(Java Exceution Time Measurement) library. It can be easily integrated with spring . For using JETM you will have to add JETM dependency and some modification of the application context file.The execution time can be checked on a browser.